# How to guess what version of a package is available on Melpa?

Tags: package-repositories

I want to check if there is an update for the `org` package every time my emacs daemon starts. I was looking at package.el for clues on how to check if the current version of a package was older than the version available in the package repository of GNU and Org, but I couldn't follow the code in `package-menu--find-upgrades`, so I'm not sure how should I get the package version of the installed package and the version of the package available for the upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the package: [`auto-package-update`](https://github.com/rranelli/auto-package-update.el)

> This package provides functionality for automatically updating your
>   Emacs packages periodically. It is specially useful for people that
>   work in multiple machines and tend to forget to manually update
>   packages from time to time.
>
> The main idea is that you set a desired periodicity for the updates,
>   and when you start Emacs, the packages will be automatically updated
>   if enough days have passed since the last update.

[This snippet](https://github.com/rranelli/auto-package-update.el/blob/master/auto-package-update.el#L220:L228) shows you if a package is up-to-date:

```el
(require 'package)
(let* ((newest-desc (cadr (assq package package-archive-contents)))
           (installed-desc (cadr (or (assq package package-alist)
                                     (assq package package--builtins))))
           (newest-version  (package-desc-version newest-desc))
           (installed-version (package-desc-version installed-desc)))
      (version-list-<= newest-version installed-version))
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution. It is necessary to have all-inclusive answers. If the answer has links that point to external web-sites, then there is no guarantee that that link is function as now in future; thus deeming the answer useless. You can put the link as reference, but please also provide the necessary code within the answer itself.